# how to add new object in array in my case

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got this code on stackoverflow and I've learned, but still I don't really understand how it works. i can't add two comments to a one post.
I need this to make API that has concept like tree.

this my code :

```
  var ngaray = [];

  var json = [];
  json[0] = {};
  var komen = json[0];

  komen["post"] = "im mad";
  komen[ngaray[0] = "comment"] = {};
  komen = komen[ngaray[0]];

  komen["message"] = "why?";
  komen[ngaray[1] = "comment"] = {};
  komen = komen[ngaray[1]];

  json[1] = {};
  var komen = json[1];

  komen["post"] = "dont worry";
  komen[ngaray[0] = "comment"] = {};
  komen = komen["okay!"];

 console.log(json);
```

current results:

```
[
    {
        "post": "im mad",
        "comment": {
            "message": "why?",
            "comment": {}
        }
    },
    {
        "post": "dont worry",
        "comment": {}
    }
]
```

result i expected :

```
[
    {
        "post": "im mad",
        "comment": [{
            "message": "why?",
            "comment": {}
        },
        {
            "message": "why bro?",
            "comment": {}
        }]
    },
    {
        "post": "dont worry",
        "comment": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: I can't seem to find the part where you add the `why bro` part, can you add where you added it?

Comment: that part is my expected result, not yet exist in code

Comment: In line 8, you’re declaring "comment" as `{}` instead of the `[]` you seem to be expecting. That being said, if you rewrite this without unnecessary variable reuse or, better even, without flattening your structure (think `json[0].comments[0].message` instead of countless assignments), the issues will be much easier to spot.